# Is SSDT integrated in VS 2013 Express better than the standalone version with VS 2012 shell?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I am using the standalone version of SSDT with VS 2012 shell and I was wondering if there is any point for me to upgrade to VS 2013 Express.

Are they practically the same thing and updated through different channels or the one integrated in VS 2013 has better capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are exactly the same thing, updated through different channels. There's more information on supported versions in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx) by Jill McClenahan, but right now SSDT has identical functionality in both. The benefit of upgrading is that the Express version has nicer integration with other tools and services such as cloud services, other programming languages etc. If you just care about database development that might not make much difference.